# Configuring redirect with ip address in apache2

Tags: apache2

I am not an expert in configuring apache but I have issue which needs to be resolved. Below is my virtual host apache configuration which BTW is working perfectly fine. The issue is google search is somehow showing my IP address instead my domain name.

```
<virtualHost somesite.com:80>
        ServerName www.somesite.com
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "fbclid=" [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

So now I know I need to redirect my IP Address, so i used the below solution and this seems to be not working for me. Moreover HTTP site is not opening for which I have attached the screenshot. However the secure version of my site is working. All I want is a solution to redirect my IP Address to domain name so this means when a user is clicking on the IP address in google search, it should open the secure HTTPS domain name. Please help me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.11\.111\.11$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.somesite.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Below is the error screenshot when opening HTTP based version of my site

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three rewrite rules in your config:

```
# Rule 1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "fbclid=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
# Rule 2
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
# Rule 3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.11\.111\.11$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.somesite.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Since they are applied in sequence and rule 2 has no condition, it overrides rule 3. Change the order of the rules:

```
# Rule 1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "fbclid=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
# Rule 3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.11\.111\.11$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.somesite.com$1 [R=301,L]
# Rule 2
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thank you @Piotr. Your solution worked for me.